# Incorrect root element and customizing the namespace using soap client

Tags: node-soap

I am using node soap client for calling a SOAP webservice from Node js script

**I have couple of issues**

1. I am getting the below error from server( after request submit ) where the root element is not as per the WSDL document. Looks like it is picking up the message element from WSDL

   ```
    err : Error: soapenv:Server: error: The document is not a getAuthorizationRequest@http://www.xyzabcdefgh.com/auth/operations/2009/3: document element mismatch got getAuthorizationRequestMsg
   ```
2. I would like know to how to add custom namespaces as the element fields are generated without any namespace

My client code looks as follows

```
soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        client.addSoapHeader("<User.SessionId>sessionid</User.SessionId>")
        client.getAuthorizationInfo( { 'atns:authenticationCtx': { attributes: {    accessTypeCode: 
                                                     "XYZ"} } }, 
         function(err, result, rawResponse, soapHeader, rawRequest) {
            // result is a javascript object
            console.log("err : "+err);
        });
    }
});
```